# React Navigation Hardware Back Button exiting app from evey screen

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, mobx-react

i've got my app currently set up like this from the root: -

```
-SwitchNavigator
 -Splash (Also decides if you have a token or not and where to send you...)
 -AuthFlow (If no Token...)
  -Login Screen
 -SecureFlow (If a Token exists...)
```

SecureFlow looks like this: -

(MobX Provider)

```
<Provider store={stores}>
    <DrawerNavigator />
</Provider>
```

Then the DrawerNavigator is as follows: -

```
-DrawerNavigator
 -StackNavigator
  -Home(Main screen once authenticated)
  -StackNavigator (Screen1)
   -Screen1a
   -Screen1b
   -Screen1c
  -Screen2
  -Screen3
  -Screen4
```

React-Navigation version is 2.2.5

So, for whatever reason, if I press the hardware back button from say Screen1a or even Screen3 the App closes rather than actually navigates back... The built in Navigator back buttons work fine.

Anybody know why this is?

I've read about people running Redux have to manually setup the back button behaviour but is that the case here with MobX?

It doesn't seem like MobX or React Navigation have much to do with each other in my implementation?

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty impossible to gauge a respectable correct answer here, without reviewing your code.

Nonetheless, this could be due to your android react-native stack, or more likely how your routes are stacked.

My advice would be to employ the react-native-router-flux package to manage this:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-router-flux

This has Mobx already built-in and you can also pass data via Actions() if not full conversant with Mobx stateless constructs.

Answer (score -1):

There's possibly a `return true` missing in your back handler.